# Usage of org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher when launching a Spring Boot app with a dynamic main class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, parameters, command-line-interface

I'm experimenting with an ability of Spring Boot to start a main class supplied to it via `-Dloader.main` parameter, as described [in its documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html).

Currently we use Spring Boot 2.7.13.

Here's a simple shell for a sample Boot application with a `main()` being executed:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:feeds-config.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class DownstreamDataFactoryApplication implements CommandLineRunner { 
            
        
    @Autowired
    private DataAcquisitionService dataAcquisitionService;
    
    @Autowired
    private DataMarshallerService dataMarshallerService;
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DownstreamDataFactoryApplication.class)
          .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
          .run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Starting execution");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            log.info("args[{}]: {}", i, args[i]);
        }
        
        //read data
        Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>();
        //Flux<?> data = dataAcquisitionService.obtainData(context);
        List<?> data = dataAcquisitionService.obtainData(context);
        log.info("Obtained data: "+data);
        
        //process data
        log.info("Processed data: ");
        
        //write data
        //log.debug("Report saved to {}", dataMarshallerService.getOutputFileLocation());
        //log.debug("Ending execution");
        log.info("Marshalled data to a file: ");
        
        //distribute data
        log.info("Send marshalled data to a remote location: ");
    }

}
```

My goal is to have several independent Spring Boot applications segregated by package structure in the codebase such that depending on what's being passed via `-Dloader.main`different Boot application is being run.

Consequently, the `mainClass` stanza in `spring-boot-maven-plugin`'s section is disabled:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>
                     <!-- 
                    com.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication
                    -->
                    </mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
    </plugin>
```

So far, so good.

What I'm noticing is that the runtime seems to behave exactly the same whether I'm passing the `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher` as a second argument or not.

Here's what the output looks like with the `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher` being supplied:

```
>java -jar target\downstream-data-factory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dloader.main=com.xxx.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher


2023-07-31 16:14:03.287 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Started DownstreamDataFactoryApplication in 2.981 seconds (JVM running for 4.425)
2023-07-31 16:14:03.291 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2023-07-31 16:14:03.292 [main] DEBUG c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Starting execution
2023-07-31 16:14:03.293 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - args[0]: -Dloader.main=com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication
2023-07-31 16:14:03.293 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - args[1]: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
2023-07-31 16:14:03.294 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Obtained data: null
2023-07-31 16:14:03.295 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Processed data:
2023-07-31 16:14:03.296 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Marshalled data to a file:
2023-07-31 16:14:03.297 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Marshalled data to a remote location:
2023-07-31 16:14:03.300 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2023-07-31 16:14:03.306 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6c130c45, started on Mon Jul 31 16:14:01 EDT 2023
2023-07-31 16:14:03.310 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase -2147483647
2023-07-31 16:14:03.311 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'springBootLoggingLifecycle' completed its stop procedure
```

and without it being supplied:

```
>java -jar target\downstream-data-factory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dloader.main=com.xxx.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication


2023-07-31 16:18:39.720 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Started DownstreamDataFactoryApplication in 2.931 seconds (JVM running for 4.313)
2023-07-31 16:18:39.725 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2023-07-31 16:18:39.726 [main] DEBUG c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Starting execution
2023-07-31 16:18:39.726 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - args[0]: -Dloader.main=com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication
2023-07-31 16:18:39.728 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Obtained data: null
2023-07-31 16:18:39.728 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Processed data:
2023-07-31 16:18:39.729 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Marshalled data to a file:
2023-07-31 16:18:39.729 [main] INFO  c.p.g.f.d.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication - Marshalled data to a remote location:
2023-07-31 16:18:39.731 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean - Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2023-07-31 16:18:39.734 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6c130c45, started on Mon Jul 31 16:18:37 EDT 2023
2023-07-31 16:18:39.739 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase -2147483647
2023-07-31 16:18:39.740 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Bean 'springBootLoggingLifecycle' completed its stop procedure
```

My assumption was that the `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`carries within itself certain keys that the mainclass-less invocation via `-Dloader.main=AppwithMainMethod` would be dependent upon and would otherwise failed, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

What are the proper use cases for this `PropertiesLauncher` parameter with some samples and documentation?  Is it optional? Required? Can one safely skip supplying it? When?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `-jar` does exactly what it is supposed to do, launch a jar, it will ignore everything else. If you want to use the `PropertiesLauncher` you have to use `-cp` (classpath) to make the jar part of the classpath instead for it to being launched. Removing the `Main-Class` will not remove it from the manifest, as the main is alway the `JarLauncher` and it will detect the `Start-Class` (IIRC).

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76811967/3710490 and you can run just with `java -jar target\downstream-data-factory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score -1):

In the command line:

```
java -jar target\downstream-data-factory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dloader.main=com.xxx.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

The strings `-Dloader.main=com.xxx.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.DownstreamDataFactoryApplication` and `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher` are passed to `main` as command line parameters. They aren't interpreted by `java` or Spring Boot.

The correct command line is:

```
java -Dloader.main=com.example.demo.DemoApplication3 \
  -cp target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

assuming that your application class is `com.example.demo.DemoApplication3`

I would have expected that setting the `mainClass` to `org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher` in the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` configuration would have allowed this to work with `-jar`, but that gives me a stack overflow error.

That jar was built with a plain config:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.demo.DemoApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

You can set `mainClass` to whatever you like -- one of the applications, to use as a default, or a class which gives a usage message if `loader.main` hasn't been set and the jar is run with `-jar`.