# Spring Boot with multiple entry points applications via Maven profiles

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm trying to prototype a structure in which several @SpringBootApplications are segregated by means of their packaging namespaces, like so:

[image: ![enter image description here]

In Maven `pom.xml`, to build, I'm relying on profiles, as shown below, and described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html):

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                ${spring.boot.mainclass}
                            </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dcr</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>other</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

My attempts to build the codebase (per spring-boot-maven-plugin [spec](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html)) result in the following:

```
>mvn clear package -Drun.profiles=dcr



[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage (repackage) on project downstream-data-factory: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication, com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage (repackage) on project downstream-data-factory: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication, com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication, com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication, com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder$SingleMainClassCallback.getMainClassName (MainClassFinder.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder$SingleMainClassCallback.access$100 (MainClassFinder.java:403)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.MainClassFinder.findSingleMainClass (MainClassFinder.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.findMainMethod (Packager.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.findMainMethodWithTimeoutWarning (Packager.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.getMainClass (Packager.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.addMainAndStartAttributes (Packager.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.buildManifest (Packager.java:267)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.write (Packager.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Packager.write (Packager.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage (Repackager.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage (Repackager.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.repackage (RepackageMojo.java:216)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.execute (RepackageMojo.java:206)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
```

Though [the above reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html) suggests invocation via `-Drun.profiles=dcr`, the regular Maven way, via `-P dcr` was also tried, unsuccessfully.  It returns the same error message.

What am I missing?

The above approach is also referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42840829/283837) - is that answer incrorrect?

Thank you in advance.

---

Some further experiments lead me to believe that the culprit is somewhere within the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`configuration/invocation as even when I disable profiles stanza in `pom.xml` completely, the error message remains the same, it doesn't distinguish between the 2 profiles and doesn't substitute the `${spring.boot.mainclass}` property:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                ${spring.boot.mainclass}
                            </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<!-- 
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dcr</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>other</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
-->
</project>
```

The same error persists when `plugins` are configured slightly differently, without using profiles:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage-dcr</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication</mainClass>
                        <finalName>dcr</finalName>
                        <outputDirectory>target/apps</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage-other</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication</mainClass>
                        <finalName>other</finalName>
                        <outputDirectory>target/apps</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and invoked with simple `mvn clean package`.

Reading more carefully into the [Spring Boot Maven plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging), looks like it's not intended to recognize Maven profiles at all, making the foundation on which this experiment is based, referred to [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42840829/283837) so much shakier:

[image]

Full `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.pru.globalpayments</groupId>
    <artifactId>downstream-data-factory</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>downstream-data-factory</name>
    <description>Contains logic for generation of feeds expected by the downstream systems</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <sonar.language>js</sonar.language>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.beanio</groupId>
            <artifactId>beanio</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.datafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>datafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jeasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>easy-random-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>
                        ${spring.boot.mainclass}
                    </mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dcr</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>other</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.boot.mainclass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Please post the error messages as text, not an image.

Comment: Oh, and your pom.xml too. Please read [ask].

Comment: `run.profiles` is not how you select a maven profile. You want `-P dcr`

Comment: You can try following this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class

Comment: I tried that article, as I tend to do my own research prior to posting, but that approach doesn't provide the ability to have several @SpringApplications configured in a single codebase.  Here's my related question on that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76806971/283837

Comment: Are you trying to have a single executable jar containing several applications?

Comment: As is noted in my question and, according to the answers referred to, should be possible.

Comment: Anything you do via maven profiles is build time, not run time. The approach you are asking about in this question is not going to give you several applications in a single executable jar.

Comment: Can you share please any *Application.java content to verify `@Profile` is set correctly?

Comment: @Valijon I only tried using Maven profiles, no Spring ones at this point.  You could find a source for the `*Application.java` in another ticket I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76806971/283837

Answer (score 0):

Seems `mainClass` configuration is not placed in the right place:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>                        
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging

```
$ mvn clean package -P other
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------< com.pru.globalpayments:downstream-data-factory >-----------
[INFO] Building downstream-data-factory 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\workspace\downstream-data-factory\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\workspace\downstream-data-factory\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\workspace\downstream-data-factory\target\downstream-data-factory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage (repackage) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage (default) @ downstream-data-factory ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  17.005 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-01T16:52:35+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ java -jar target/downstream-data-factory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication running...

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.13)

2023-08-01 16:52:41.465  INFO 8480 --- [           main] .d.a.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication : Starting AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_311 on X with PID 8480 (D:\workspace\downstream-data-factory\target\downstream-data-factory-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by Valijon in D:\workspace\downstream-data-factory)
2023-08-01 16:52:41.487  INFO 8480 --- [           main] .d.a.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-08-01 16:52:48.635  INFO 8480 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 8080
2023-08-01 16:52:48.667  INFO 8480 --- [           main] .d.a.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication : Started AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication in 8.93 seconds (JVM running for 10.584)
```

Comment: This is failing with the same error: ```[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage[m [1m(repackage)[m on project [36mdownstream-data-factory[m: [1;31mExecution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication, com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.DcrDataFactoryApplication][m -> [1m[Help 1][m```

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon I've tested with `spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.1.2`. Let me see previous versions

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon with `spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.13` works fine!

Comment: My version is 2.7.13 as is clear from the error message.  In any case, looks like this plugin doesn't recognize Maven profiles, see my updates.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon please, update your question and share your current `spring-boot-maven-plugin` setup

Comment: Do you have some codebase you could link to to see what works fine for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254750/discussion-between-valijon-and-simeon-leyzerzon).

Comment: I cannot use chat - it is blocked for me here.  What do you mean by `spring-boot-maven-plugin` setup?  I could post the whole `pom.xml` if that helps

Comment: can you share pom.xml?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon try please https://github.com/Valijon/downstream-data-factory

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon also try to remove `spring-boot-maven-plugin` files and run `mvn clean package -P dcr` to download them again: `C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-maven-plugin\2.7.13`

Comment: Thanks, will try running that minimal version in a separate repo shortly.  Also, seeing a bit of a discrepancy where the fully classified name of the `AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication` is `com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication` according to your package definition but supposedly gets picked by `<spring.boot.mainclass>com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.anothersystem.AnotherSystemDataFactoryApplication</spring.boot.mainclass>` in the pom.xml.  You ran it via `mvn clean package -P other`?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon yes, i will share all `mvn clean package -P other` traces